# Why "rising" is used in "From here we can watch the ___________ of the sun"

Tags: articles, gerunds, exam-questions, catenative-verbs

> From here we can watch the ________ of the sun

Options given are A.**rise** / B.**rising** / C.**risen** / D.**rose**

The given answer is **rising**.

Why is this gerund given as the answer?

I checked the **catenative verbs followed by a gerund** list in Wiktionary, and **watch** is not included.

So I am under the assumption that a **noun** should come after article **the**. Therefore gerund fits here. Is this correct?

Comment: "From here we can watch the rising of the sun" is a more poetic way of saying "From here we can watch the sun rise". The meaning is essentially identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no catenation here. **Watch** is being used in its ordinary sense. Consider this:

> We can watch the sun.

I'm sure you see that **the sun** is the object of **watch**. So whatever follows **watch** will normally be a noun phrase of some kind.

That is why **rising** is used. To be a noun phrase, a verb must be transformed into a gerund.

And because **rising** is a pretty concrete idea, an article is required. Thus, **the rising of the sun**.