# Is this obsolete English?

Tags: archaic-language

I came across this sentence:

> He enforced the **maintaining** of all bona-fide transactions in clergy property, but advocated the revision of such contracts as might be proved fraudulent, and urged a concordat proposing that the state provide for the support of the clergy.

*Maximilian in Mexico - Woman's Reminiscences of the French Intervention 1862-1867 Sara Yorke Stevenson*

Why would the author use maintaining instead of maintenance? I couldn't find maintaining as a noun anywhere on the net and I am pretty sure she is using it as a noun which again it seems is not one of the meanings of the wor maintaining.

Is this an old fashion word?

Comment: Don't assume something in print is well written. I think here they are trying to say that he wanted bona fide transactions to be continued, rather than that he thought they needed maintenance (so to speak).

Comment: It's just formal English, not a mistake.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why "rising" is used in "From here we can watch the \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_ of the sun"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/292308/why-rising-is-used-in-from-here-we-can-watch-the-of-the-sun)

Comment: **Maintaining** is a perfectly good noun. "The **maintaining** of a house can be expensive."

Answer (score -1):

In the given sentence, "maintaining" is used as a gerund, which is a verb form that can function as a noun. While "maintaining" is commonly used as a verb, it can also be used as a noun in certain contexts to refer to the act or process of keeping something in a certain condition or state.

Using gerunds as nouns is a common grammatical construction in English, not old-fashioned or wrong. While it may not be as commonly used in everyday speech, it is still grammatically correct and can be found in formal or written language.

Comment: It is not a verb form functioning as a noun, it's a noun functioning as a noun.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. "Maintain" is a verb, add -ing to make it a gerund enables it to function as a noun.

Comment: No. A gerund cannot have a determiner and will take a direct object not an oblique. In OP’s sentence the -img form is a deverbal noun, not a gerund.